# AVAudioPlayer does not play sound on some devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have an app that uses AVAudioPlayer to play sound effects, music, etc. It works fine for just about every user (100,000+ users), but I've had several reports of sound not playing at all even though sound effects are working on other apps on the same device. The bug has gone away for some users after an app restart/device reboot, but for others it continues to persist. AVSpeechSynthesizer isn't working for these users either.

I haven't been able to reproduce the bug to see if the AVAudioPlayer is throwing an error, so I'm not sure if it is - but I don't see why it would be working fine for 99.9% of users and not this tiny subset.

Has anyone else run into something like this?

Here's the code I'm using to set up the player:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:@"AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient" error:nil];

NSString *file = [filename stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString *extension = [filename pathExtension];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:file withExtension:extension];

self.soundPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&error];
[self.soundPlayer1 prepareToPlay];
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Everything works perfectly on my device, but throwing the error on the iPhone of my customer. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Nope, still no idea what's causing this. Haven't heard any reports since the upgrade to iOS 8, but that doesn't mean anything - the problem was pretty rare.

Comment: Same problem under iOS8.3. After a device reboot, it plays the sound. I never had the problem on my own devices or the sim, so I have no idea what it going on.

Comment: Update - I'm still getting sporadic reports of this issue on iOS 8. The strange thing is, the affected users can hear the sounds if they plug headphones in.

Comment: Did these users connect an USB device (e.g. Alesis iDock)  to the lightning port? I currently have a customer who also has this problem. Switching to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` seems to work.

Comment: No devices connected via USB or Bluetooth. And changing the AVAudioSession category doesn't seem to help. I'm starting to wonder if this is a bug with AVSpeechSynthesizer, which I use throughout my apps but isn't used that much in other apps - would explain why this issue doesn't seem to be cropping up for others.